# VLOOKUP not working correctly between two different workbooks

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to get some values between two different workbooks.
One workbook is named 'BSC_AGRvF.xlsm' and the other is 'BSC_AGERE_SQL_v1.xlsx', both are being used on excel office 365.

I used `=VLOOKUP(A2;[BSC_AGERE_SQL_v1.xlsx]Variavéis'!$A$4:$E$1000;4;FALSE)` to find the description of certain code that is stored in A2 in the current workbook ('BSC_AGRvF.xlsm') but the result is #N/A.

I also tried to use `=INDEX([BSC_AGERE_SQL_v1.xlsx]Variavéis'!$D$4:$D$1000;MATCH(1;INDEX(([BSC_AGERE_SQL_v1.xlsx]Variavéis'!$C$4:$C$1000=A2););0))` but the result is the same (#N/A).

The formulas seem to be correct as far as I know but the error keeps occurring. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: HAve you checked that there is a value for sure? I mean, are you sure that in column A of workbook `BSC_AGERE_SQL_v1` exists the vlaue of `A2`? Also,  could be that in the own workbook of `BSC_AGERE_SQL_v1` the cell at column D you are trying to get throws an error and vlookup brings the error. Also, make sure that what you are searching is same data type that where you are searching (text with text, numbers with numbers, but not mixed). Also check there is no extra hidden chars, blanks at start/end, and so on

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Yes, the value from ```A2``` exists in ```BSC_AGERE_SQL_v1``` because it comes from that same workbook aswell. ```A2``` = ```=[BSC_AGERE_SQL_v1.xlsx]Variavéis!$C$5```

Comment: mmmm...could be that you are missing a single quote before workbook name? try `=VLOOKUP(A2;'[BSC_AGERE_SQL_v1.xlsx]Variavéis'!$A$4:$E$1000;4;FALSE)`

Comment: Tried that, still the same result.

Comment: Well, without seeing the files then, can't do anything else I'm afraid. What if you try on a different workbook? is calculation mode automatic? Have you tried redoing the formula from zero?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns I limited the range from ```A4:E1000 to C4:E1000```. So now I have ```=VLOOKUP(A2;[BSC_AGERE_SQL_v1.xlsx]Variavéis'!$C$4:$E$1000;2;FALSE)``` and it worked fine. I think the error occurred because of the only searching right limitation and because it would have to search starting from column A of that workbook (which is left from where the A2 is stored - it is on column C).

Comment: VLOOKUP searchs for a value in the most left column of the range you select. If you select `!$C$4:$E$1000` it will search in column C. If you select `A4:E1000` it will search in A. If it works using column C, means you did the formula wrong.

Comment: The index match formula should be : `=INDEX([BSC_AGERE_SQL_v1.xlsx]Variavéis'!$D$4:$D$1000;MATCH(A2;[BSC_AGERE_SQL_v1.xlsx]Variavéis'!$C$4:$C$1000=;0))` Have a try..